# Are assembly language programs restricted by kernel modes as well?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

If I were to write an assembly language program, am I allowed to break the security mechanisms of an OS - accessing other processes' address space, accessing kernel address space, etc?

**Edit** :

If I write an assembly language program which is loaded in memory by an OS supplied loader, how would the OS intercept my program while it tries to access protected memory address spaces? My assumption is this protection is built into the system calls and libraries supplied by an OS, and if you don't use those system calls and libraries, you're allowed to break OS policies.

Comment: Of course not. Security is not a matter of knowledge. The CPU deals only with machine code, independently of the language used to generate it.

Comment: RE your edit: No. The protection is built into the operating system itself. Your assembly language program will run as a standard process, and is subject to the same security restrictions as any other process.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you elaborate on how the interception happens when a program not using OS's system calls and libraries tries to access protected memory address spaces?

Comment: The OS stops it. It works in exactly the same way as a program written in any other language. All modern operating systems implement protected memory and run each program in its own process, such that one process is not allowed to mess with the memory of other processes (or the system itself). This literally has nothing to do with assembly language and everything to do with the design of an operating system.

Comment: Memory protection, and virtualization are generally supplied by modern hardware(CPU). The OS developers use those features to sandbox code in their own process space. The OS will determine what restrictions are placed on code. Whether the code was hand written assembly or compiled by a high level language all the code executed will have the same restrictions.

Comment: @BharatKhatri, bro, I guess it would be pretty helpful for you if you can get a copy of Tom Shanley's book "Protected Mode Software Architecture". This book has a very nice introduction from the 'why' you need a 'protected mode' CPU architecture to provide shelter for a modern OS to the 'how' are some OS parts implemented with these CPU features. Of course, there are some little details missing (if not I wouldn't be here searching for answers) but it gives you plenty of info to begin with.

Comment: @fante Thanks, I'll get a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE** : This answer is an amalgamation of the answers provided by [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter), [glauxosdever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7014281/glauxosdever) and [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), and comments provided by [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)

---

Not if your program is run as an OS-controlled process, on a machine that provides adequate process isolation (typically **address space management protection**) in hardware.

For most architectures (including x86), protection is built-in into the hardware.

Most modern operating systems (including Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD, etc) use paging for memory management of processes. Paging involves having page directories and page tables, which describe the properties of each virtual page: physical address, permissions, etc.

**Page directories and page tables are mapped in kernel space and therefore can't be edited by user processes.**

Every single load/store (and code fetch) is checked against the page tables (using a [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) to cache page table entries).

Also, privileged instructions like x86's [LIDT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) fault if run by a user-space process. (The exceptions section of that manual entry says it raises #GP(0) "If the current privilege level is not 0").

Answer (score 5):

For most architectures (including x86), protection is built-in into the hardware.

For x86, there are two techniques for protecting the address space of the kernel and the other programs: segmentation and paging. Most modern operating systems (including Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD, etc) use paging as the main technique, so I'll talk about it.

Paging involves having page directories and page tables, which describe the properties of each virtual page: physical address, permissions, etc. Page directories and page tables are mapped in kernel space and therefore can't be edited by user processes.

When the kernel switches to a user process, it restores the page structures of the user process so it only has permission to access its own mapped pages. When it tries to access some unmapped address, a page fault will be raised. If memory contents at that address had been swapped away, they will be unswapped and the process will continue without noticing anything (apart from a small delay maybe). If that memory address hadn't been allocated and therefore not swapped away, the program will simply terminate.

*Note*: It's also not true that only assembly language can cause unsafe behaviour. Try to write to a random address in C and you will see that it will most likely crash immediately. Why? Because the OS will detect the address space violation through the page fault. In case it doesn't crash, it will mean you will have written to some memory belonging to its own address space.

Comment: Segmentation itself does not confer any protection. The protection is provided by running in *protected mode*, which gives you four "rings" (privilege levels).

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for spotting the inaccuracy, edited.

Comment: The key point that you don't mention: user-space processes can't modify their own page tables.  This is what kernel-mode (ring 0) vs. user-mode (ring 3) gives you.  I know it's hard to summarize this in a short answer, and hard to know what knowledge you can assume the reader has, but I think this bears mentioning.  I'd suggest just saying kernel vs. user mode, and don't actually mention x86 rings, since this isn't even an x86-specific question, and common OSes just use rings 0 and 3 the same way they use kernel vs. user mode on arches that only have that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you too! Edited.

Comment: @glauxosdever, I have a doubt when you say: "If that memory address hadn't been allocated and therefore not swapped away, the program will simply terminate.". How OS realizes that a particular memory address hadn't been allocated? It seems like there should be an additional 'flag' at every Page Entry to signal something like page 'Allocated/Non-Allocated', is that correct? Please explain. By the way, your above explanation is superb.

Comment: @fante : On the x86 hardware page tables (which provide the mapping between virtual and physical memory) there is a `present` flag as part of the Page Table entries, Page Directory entries etc. This is also one of the bits passed to a page fault handler for it to decide how to proceed. If the `present` bit is zero a page fault will occur.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thanx for commenting. However, that 'Present' bit is not an attribute which should be interpreted as 'Allocated/Not-Allocated'. The purpose for that flag is to signal the kernel if that page needs to be brought from 'mass storage' or if it is already in RAM. Consider that it is possible for a page to be a valid piece of an EXE but that it is in 'mass storage' right now due to insufficient space on RAM. So, there is no way to tell if that page is 'Allocated' or not just by looking at the 'Present' flag. Or Am I missing something? :-)

Comment: @fante Actually it can be interpreted however the page fault handler wishes to interpret it. Mass storage and virtual memory is only on such scenario. That flag can also be used to demand map shared memory between processes if it so choose. In fact the page fault handler can just ignore the request, let the instruction try again/fail and then fault the application. The other bits (bottom 3) specify whether the page a virtual address is on is read only or not (writing to read only will page fault for example), and whether a page allows supervisory (Priv level 0 to 2) or user space(Priv 3).

Comment: @MichaelPetch, sorry for my confusion. I just realized after re-reading your comments and the literature I have that the trick for 'unallocated' memory is to marked as 'Kernel' or 'System' in spite of being 'Present' or not!!!. So, when the User App makes calls to 'malloc' (during its lifetime) those 'unallocated' ('Kernel') pages becomes 'allocated' ('User') pages!!!. I apologize for my lapsus-brutus... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not if your program is run as an OS-controlled process, on a machine that provides adequate process isolation (typically address space management protection) in hardware.  (Well, you can write instructions that try to break security, but under a well-designed OS with such hardware all they will do is  trap when executed).

If the hardware you run on does not have such protection capabilities, then you are running in a space shared with the OS and other applications, by convention in a *cooperative* way.  That means you *could* touch and damage the OS and other applications, but you should not.  Whether you choose to violate that commitment is up to you; normally, it doesn't make you friends with community of users of that type of hardware.

Comment: If I write an assembly language program which is loaded in memory by an OS supplied loader, how would the OS intercept my program while it tries to access protected memory address spaces? My assumption is this protection is built into the system calls and libraries supplied by an OS, and if you don't use those system calls and libraries, you're allowed to break OS policies.

Comment: The OS can put anything it likes in your process address space.  Your program cannot see outside its process address space.  Nothing is breakable.

Comment: The page table contains protection bits that can be used to restrict access to the page by processor mode. If the bits are set for kernel mode access only, a user mode access triggers an access violation.

Comment: @BharatKhatri: the protection is built into the hardware.  Every single load/store is checked against the page tables (using [a TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) to cache page table entries).  Also, privileged instructions fault if run by a user-space process.  If all it took to get root on a machine was a little bit of hand-written asm, secure multi-user OSes would be impossible to implement.  Since they are, we know your premise must be wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes That explains it better. Can you also elaborate on *privileged* instructions? Are you talking about privileged instructions provided by the processor asm?

Comment: @BharatKhatri: yes, instructions like [LIDT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) which the manuals says: raises #GP(0) "If the current privilege level is not 0".

Comment: @PeterCordes LIDT is privileged of course, but on a side note Linux does allow you to make certain types of changes to the LDT through a syscall.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, that's a good example of how access to the LDT has to go through the OS, instead of being done directly, even when the OS does permit it.  (BTW, [turned these comments into an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087354/are-assembly-language-programs-restricted-by-kernel-modes-as-well/41166955#41166955))

Answer (score 4):

The protection is built into the hardware. Every single load/store (and code fetch) is checked against the page tables (using a [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) to cache page table entries).

Also, privileged instructions like x86's [LIDT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) fault if run by a user-space process.  (The exceptions section of that manual entry says it raises #GP(0) "If the current privilege level is not 0").

If all it took to get root on a machine was a little bit of hand-written asm, secure multi-user OSes would be impossible to implement. Since they exist and are actually quite common, we know your premise must be wrong. (Linux, Unix, OS X, Windows are all designed to be secure in this way.  They've all had implementation bugs that allow attackers to run arbitrary kernel code, but that's not the point.)