# How OS catches illegal memory references at paging scheme?

Tags: memory-management, x86, operating-system, paging

I am trying to understand how the OS catches all illegal memory access in a system which uses Paging. (32 bits, x86, Paging enabled).

To be more specific, let's suppose I have a tiny App which is just 1 Page in size. Considering that a MS OS take the upper half of the 'virtual memory address space' and that my tiny EXE occupies just 4k of lower half of VMAS, then:

**1)** How OS realizes that there is an 'illegal memory reference/access' going on when my code tries to write to a memory location outside from my own Exe's 4k? (Obviously, that pointer wasn't obtained from a 'malloc' or similar call).

**2)** How are Page Tables managed for that tiny Exe? Does OS have to define all 1 M Page Entries (-1 Page Entry) with a 'Non-Present' attribute set and 'System' owned? (When that 'process' is created).

Any advice or comment is wellcome.

**EDIT:**
 Just to make things clear, the answer (compiled form all generous contributions) is:

In order to catch an illegal reference for ***unallocated*** memory, the VMAS for the ***App*** should be marked as ***User & Non-Present*** and the ***rest*** of the VMAS should be marked as ***Kernel & Non-Present***.
(Of course, ***allocated*** memory is with ***User*** attribute. Take note that ***User & Non-Present*** is at 'process creation' before its first run!. After that it changes to ***User & Present***).

That way the ***hardware*** monitor will catch any access outside of the App boundary!!!
And the Page Fault handler will ***assume*** an illegal access because no ***User*** code is allowed to access (read/write) a ***Kernel*** page.

[VMAS= Virtual Memory Address Space]

Comment: *How OS realizes*: [hardware checks every access](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41166955/224132), using a [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) to cache page table entries.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanx for the links.... I just don't find and answer yet to: How OS realizes an illegal memory access is going on unallocated memory? And what measures OS takes at Page Entries and the Exception handler to identify them? I mean, if the answer is to mark all 1 M Page Entries - 1 Page Entry (refering to the example above) as 'Kernel' pages then there is a 4MB bulky writes to be done just to get all Page Entries properly initialized @ that 'process' creation!!!...

Comment: At each level of the paging data structures (all the way down to a page table entry), bit 0 of the entry is the `present` bit. If that bit is clear for a lookup a virtual address will cause the page fault handler in the OS to fire, at which time the OS decides what to do. It could associate a page already in physical memory; read data from disk into a free physical page and then map it to the virtual address space and continue; could just do nothing and cause the request to fault when retried; or whatever else the OS chooses to do.

Comment: Depending on the mode you are in (assuming we are talking x86), and the page options set pages can be 4k, 2mb, 4mb, and 1gb. It depends on how the OS configured things, what mode it is operating in, and what the hardware supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How OS realizes that there is an 'illegal memory reference/access' going on when my code tries to write to a memory location outside from my own Exe's 4k? (Obviously, that pointer wasn't obtained from a 'malloc' or similar call).

A sequence of events has to take place. The processor takes as inputs (a) the logical page being accessed; (b) the type of access; and (c) the processor mode to determine whether an access is valid.

1. Is there a page table entry for the page? If not => access violation
2. Is the page table entry marked valid?
   The processing here is system specific, depending upon whether the page tables can distinguish between an invalid page table entry and an valid entry that is not mapped to a page frame. In the former case => access violation. In the latter case, it triggers a page fault and the OS has to determine whether to trigger an access violation or load the page.
3. Does the page table permit the type of access for the current processor mode? If not => access violation.

If the hardware triggers an access violation exception, it switches to kernel mode and invokes the OS's access violation handler.

> 2) How are Page Tables managed for that tiny Exe? Does OS have to define all 1 M Page Entries (-1 Page Entry) with a 'Non-Present' attribute set and 'System' owned? (When that 'process' is created).

Operating systems provide system services for mapping memory into the process address space. Generally, the program loader reads the instructions in the EXE file and calls page mapping system services to set up the initial state of the application.

When this occurs depends upon the operating system. In eunuchs-land, a process is a clone of its parent. The running of a program takes place in an exec___ system call. Some operating system have a background command processor that allows multiple applications to be run sequentially within a single process.

From there, it is up to the application to manage the pages mapped to its address space. That is done by calling system services. For example "malloc" calls will cause the application to use system services to map pages.

The initial state of the application is likely to have holes of invalid user addresses. In fact, the range of valid addresses is not likely to be contiguous within the logical address space.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each page has, among others, the following attributes: *Present* and *Read/Write*.
   Accessing a page that is not present, or writing a read-only page, generates a privileged event called a *page fault*. This event takes the form of the CPU executing a specific routine that the OS set up. 
   Hence the OS is informed of the event and the attempt that was made.
2. The structures used to implement paging are hierarchical: pages are grouped into directories, and directory into higher directories. There are usually four levels.
   Like in a file system, only the directories needed to reach the specific page need to be created.

A definitive source of information is the [Intel manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm), specifically the third volume.

---

<sub>This answer intentionally uses simplified words.</sub>

Comment: So at 'process creation' one Page Directory and one Page Table needs to be initialized by the OS. Thats 8KB of data!!! Well, it is better than writing a 4MB chunk!. (Assuming x86-32bit).

Answer (score 0):

> How OS realizes that there is an 'illegal memory reference/access' going on when my code tries to write to a memory location outside from my own Exe's 4k? (Obviously, that pointer wasn't obtained from a 'malloc' or similar call).

A page fault is raised and the page fault handler gets executed. In the case of an invalid memory access it terminates the program. In the case of an access of swapped memory, it restores the memory contents from the disk into the main memory again and lets the program continue.

> How are Page Tables managed for that tiny Exe? Does OS have to define all 1 M Page Entries (-1 Page Entry) with a 'Non-Present' attribute set and 'System' owned? (When that 'process' is created).

On x86, there are two-level page structures: page directories and page tables. Assuming your program fits in a single page, the OS will initialise a page directory that contains only one valid entry pointing to a page table, and only one valid entry pointing to the page containing the needed memory.